# Paypal Integration with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I'm looking to implement a very simple Paypal integration whereby I can enter a valid Paypal Email address (recipient) and a dollar amount, and click "Pay." Ideally, it would send the money from my paypal account automatically via my API key.

I currently have Mass Pay set up with PHP, and it's working fine, except that it charges me 2% on every payment, and doesn't pass back the Transaction ID. It also kinda seems unnecessary since I don't need to pay multiple people at once.

Since I only need to do one transaction at a time, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a simpler Paypal API for single outgoing transactions from my account.

I've been reading the documentation all day and I've yet to find what I'm looking for.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're using Website Payments Pro, then you will be charged on every transaction regardless of which API operation you use. For simpler API operations, you may use the Direct Payment API or Express Checkout API, both typically used for singular transactions. If you use Website Payment Standards, you will not incur the 2% per-transaction fee, but not have the luxury of using Paypal's API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal has sample [codes for integrating various PayPal features](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code) on it's website. This includes PHP take a look at the list of features and I'm sure what you are looking for is there.

Also from the paypal site:

> PayPal receives the MassPay request and returns a response indicating
>   success or failure. If PayPal returns a successful response, then
>   PayPal processes the payments and, if you have Instant Payment
>   Notifications (IPN) enabled, PayPal sends a notification to the Notify
>   URL specified in your account profile. If you do not have IPN enabled,
>   you can view the details of the MassPay transaction in your PayPal
>   account.

This implies that in the case of mass pay you need to provide a URL where paypal sends payment notifications. Your program can probably check this url to figure out whether a payment has been made or not, I would suspect this would be the case for all payment integration. That being said I would `print_r` the the response from paypal, I'm sure something like a transaction id will probably be in there. [In the case of DoAuthorization it does return the transaction id](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoAuthorization)

[In the case of mass pay it does return the transaction id if IPN is enabled](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay)

Comment: Doesn't seem like any of those allow me to send a single payment. Closest listed there one is MassPay which I mentioned above.

Comment: I've added more detail to the response, however it seems your problem (except for the commission) could be solved by implementing IPN (Instant Payment Notification)